# The product of primitive polynomials is primitive.

Tags: polynomials

How can I prove that The product of primitive polynomials is primitive.

(Definition: A polynomial f(x) ∈ Q[x] is said primitive if the coefficients are integers and the maximum common divisor of the coefficients is 1)

Comment: Hi @pedro97! How have you tried to prove it? What approaches have you done so far? We won’t do homework for you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)